# Mysql Load-dta-infile file having only one enclosed string in each line

Tags: load-data-infile

I have text file which has only one string which is enclosed by "" in each line, while i am loading this file to table but it is not recognizing \r\n as new line character. If i have two columns in one line ("",integer) it's working fine.

**Text file having data like:**

```
"gmail.com"
"facebook.com"
"yahoo.com"
"goindigo.com"
"snapdeel.com"
"flipkart.com"
"ebay.com"
"godady.com"
"twiter.com"  
"gmail.com"
"facebook.com"
"yahoo.com"
"goindigo.com"
"snapdeel.com"
"flipkart.com"
```

***I am trying to load this file into Table using Query***

```
Load Query: load data local infile 'file.LOG' into table table_name fields terminated by '  ' enclosed by '"' (column);
```

here terminated by field is "\t"

***It's loading into table like:***

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ('\"gmail.com\"\r\n\"facebook.com\"\r\n\"yahoo.com\"\r\n\"goindigo.com\"\r\n\"snapdeel.com\"\r\n\"flipkart.com\"\r\n\"ebay.com\"\r\n\"godady.com\"\r\n\"twiter.com\"\r\n\"gmail.com\"\r\n\"facebook.com\"\r\n\"yahoo.com\"\r\n\"goindigo.com\"\r\n\"snapdeel.com\"\r\n\"flipkart.com\"\r\n\');
```

Entire file loading as a single line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found that if enclosed by(") followed by new line  **LOAD DATA
>   INFILE** query will not identifies the new line character by default
>   we have to mention LINES TERMINATED BY field then only it will
>   identifies the new line character.

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

to your "LOAD DATA INFILE " query

Comment: Thank you for you reply Eric,  But in mysql it default takes the '\r\n' as terminated by field, my doubt is, it is not recognized only this scenario. if line ending with number it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\test.csv' INTO TABLE test 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
LINES 
STARTING BY "\""
TERMINATED BY "\""
(col1)
;
```

Comment: thanks Eric it will work well for above code. My question is why default line terminate by is not working in this case.